# Image corrupt or truncated: Google API

Tags: image, firefox, dictionary, truncated

Its my page where we have worked http://www.pubandbar-network.co.uk/whatsonsports.php
Please check the map here. When you will click on markers for some pop up appearing and for some not.

I have checked in both firefox and chrome. In firefox got exactly the same error
Image corrupt or truncated: http://mt0.googleapis.com/vt?pb=!1m4!1m3!1i7!2i64!3i43!2m3!1e0!2sm!3i273000000!3m9!2sen-US!3sUS!5e18!12m1!1e47!12m3!1e37!2m1!1ssmartmaps!4e0

Please help